# Add Image for automated correspondence email

Tags: django, email

I am looking to add a avatar image for noreply email for automated correspondence in Django.

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean to add it as an attachment or to add it as a content?. Assuming the second one, you can put the static url for the desired avatar image as HTML content

Comment: No, I mean to add it as avatar (the photo of the sender). For example, it should be logo of the company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand this, the avatars cannot be set from django side.

If, say, you are using Gmail, you would need to make an email for no-reply@yourcompany.com and set an avatar for it there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is really work for me, but how to do not pay for the account of google apps for noreply mail?